# Google Maps marker clicks do not work on iPad when using Sencha Touch

Tags: ipad, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, extjs

Has anyone been able to get map marker clicks working on iPad? I have tried the following, which worked nicely on Google Chrome, but not on the iPad.

```
// Marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: 'Title',
    map: map,
    icon: '/images/marker.gif'
});

// Click listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    ...

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I was listening on "click" events when I should have been listening on "mousedown" events.